# How to realese Dispose() on RabbitMQ without using. C#

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

I have my sender class.

```html
public class RabbitSender
    {
        private ConnectionFactory _factory;
        private IConnection _connection;
        private IModel _channel;

        public RabbitSender()
        {
            _factory = new ConnectionFactory() { HostName = "localhost" };
            _connection = _factory.CreateConnection();
            _channel = _connection.CreateModel();
            _channel.QueueDeclare(queue: "hello",
              durable: false,
              exclusive: false,
              autoDelete: false,
              arguments: null);
        }

        public void Send(SendModel print)
        {
            byte[] messageBody = print.ToByteArray();

            _channel.BasicPublish(exchange: "",
             routingKey: "hello",
             basicProperties: null,
             body: messageBody);
        }

        public void Send2(SendModel print)
        {
            var factory = new ConnectionFactory() { HostName = "localhost" };
            using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
            using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
            {
                channel.QueueDeclare(queue: "hello",
                                     durable: false,
                                     exclusive: false,
                                     autoDelete: false,
                                     arguments: null);
                byte[] messageBody = print.ToByteArray();

                channel.BasicPublish(exchange: "",
                 routingKey: "hello",
                 basicProperties: null,
                 body: messageBody);
            }
        }
    }
```

Method `Send2()` according the documetation on the website of RabbitMQ. As u can see it is using

`using` and with it I dont have problem with memory leak. But in this case I always create new connection when call method Send2().

In case of `Send()` I create conection once but I did not use `using` in this case. Because using always close my `_channel` and I cant send next msg. 
 I try to call `_channel.Dispose()` after sending but it is the same result such with `using`. And the main problem if I will not release garbage collector my memory is leaking. In 30 minutes I use 86% of my memory :/. In case `Send2()` I dont have this problem. How I can realese once creation of connection and after each sending to clean up the garbage without closing _channel?

Comment: Is there a problem with using `Send2`? Does it do what you need? What problems do you have with it?

Comment: I need to use `send()` where I dont have `using`. Because  `using` close the channel. I need to realese garbage collector anfter sending but didnt close the channel. @Enigmativity

Comment: That's not what I asked. I want to know why can't you just use `Send2`? What is it about `Send` that is important for you to use? What's the problem with `Send2`?

Comment: because Send2 always create new connection on each call of send2(). That is why I wrote send(). I need to create connection once and use chanel

Comment: You're not answering my question. What's wrong with `Send2`? Why do you think you need to create the connection once only?

Comment: If you read with atention u must see this  in question - "Because using always close my _channel"   and I cant send next msg. That is why I need to create once _chanel but with realise Dispose(). As you know 'using' realise garb. col. and as result always close the chanel. I wrote about it in question

Answer (score 0):

I think there are probably several things going on, but the core issue is that the RabbitMQ client is not being used correctly per the documentation.

1. Connections are expensive, and should be created once per application instance. Keep the connection object around and re-use it when you need to create a new channel.
2. Channels are intended to be transient. You do not need to keep channels around - they can be disposed of after each operation. If you are doing a lot of publishes, it may be best to keep the channel around after each publish in a similar fashion as you keep the connection.
3. You'll need some logic to reconnect/re-establish your application when the connection to the server is lost.